# how to add button in jquery template for every loop

Tags: jquery

```
 var markup = "<tr><td colspan='2'><h1>${hotelname}</h1></td></tr> 
<tr><td><input type=button value=MoreInformation id=btncabinmoreinfo1></td></tr>";
    $.template("cabinTemplate", markup);
```

this dynamic button id is not working. is this correct way to create dynamic button in jquery template?

button click code:

```
$("#btncabinmoreinfo1").click(function () {
    alert("more info");
});
```

when i click this MoreInformation Button,i am not getting any alert.

Comment: hotelname is a filed name for a particular table in database

Answer (score 0):

An ID has to be unique, so if you are using it multiple times in a loop it will cause issues. It should be a class instead.

if you change it to class=btncabinmoreinfo1 and then the click event to

$(".btncabinmoreinfo1").click(function () {
    alert("more info");

you may have more luck.

Comment: instead of id!! i shoud use class?

Comment: If I understood your question correctly and this button is being used in a loop, then it should be class instead as the ID would not be unique.

Comment: yeah, that is also point, id should be unique. even i have tried class also. but that button is not responding when i click. even in Console also it is not showing any error.

Comment: did you change the click function as well to respond to the class not id, like so:

$(".btncabinmoreinfo1").click(function () {
    alert("more info");
});

Comment: yeah i have changed. its not working. Using .on() its working.

Answer (score 0):

you are doingt it wrong.you havent used quotes for id and value of input button.

```
var markup = '<tr><td colspan="2"><h1>${hotelname}</h1></td></tr> <tr><td><input type="button" value="MoreInformation" id="btncabinmoreinfo1"></td></tr>';
```

and then write click event for button:

```
$("#btncabinmoreinfo1").click(function () {
 alert("//something");
})
```

Comment: when i keep quotes in loop, it is showing error like( ;EXPECTED )

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing it as

```
var markup = "<tr><td colspan='2'><h1>${hotelname}</h1></td></tr> 
<tr><td><input type=button value=MoreInformation id=btncabinmoreinfo1></td></tr>";
    $.template("cabinTemplate", markup);
```

and appending it is some container like

```
$.tmpl( "cabinTemplate", data).appendTo( "#elementid" );
```

and then

```
$("#btncabinmoreinfo1").click(function () {
    alert("more info");
});
```

so, you can make some changes like

1. enclose your attribute value in quotes
2. and because you are doing it in loop add a class on your button.
3. attach event on your template parent like

---

```
var markup = "<tr><td colspan='2'><h1>${hotelname}</h1></td></tr> 
<tr><td><input type='button' value='MoreInformation' class='btncabinmoreinfo1'></td></tr>";
$.template("cabinTemplate", markup);

$("#elementid").on('click' , '.btncabinmoreinfo1',(function () {
    alert("more info");
});
```

You can check the use of [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) here.

A delegated-events approach attaches an event handler to only one element, the `#elementid`, and the event only needs to bubble up (from the clicked `.btncabinmoreinfo1` to `#elementid`):

So,  event will attach to `#elementid` element by clicking on `.btncabinmoreinfo1` will bubble up, so new dynamic elements can also respond to event.

I hope, It will help :)

Comment: what is the use of 'on' instead of 'click' here?